# How can i display PDF and images in android?

Tags: android, image, pdf, fragment

I have to make a fragment that can display different elements (PDF, jpg, jpeg, etc). The user can take the file from the gallery or the internal storage and i know how to do to display a PDF or a Image from gallery but i do not know how can I combine to display all this types.

Thanks!

Comment: Well,you can classify the file type and send it to different fragments for displaying. Or use a WebView tl;dr

Comment: change visibility of yiews - if user selects PDF - show PDF views, if it selects Image - show ImageVIew and hide PDF view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own widget to display these files or use several special widgets and display the content in them in turn.